# keyboard not working with games in wine

Tags: keyboard, wine, games

i have ubuntu 14.04 and wine, all up to date.

i installed Gothic and gothic 2 gold with play on linux, but the keyboard don't work.

I tried to change the windows version(xp, 7, 2000), to use some fix, like  [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1996702).

What can i do?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem before with wine but now its solved.

1. Open "configrue wine"
2. Select windows 8 in the field.
3. Open graphics tab
4. Uncheck the option "allow the window manager to control the windows"
   and then recheck it then apply--------> ok.

It worked for me maybe it can help you.

Comment: I don't have "configure wine" (or configrue wine for that matter), but the command winecfg is what you were talking about. PS: Worked great, thanks.

Comment: "configure wine" is the related PlayOnLinux button.
My input issue was unrelated to gothic, I did not need to switch to windows 8.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the only solution I found was to play the game in windowed mode. To do so, open the `Gothic.INI` file in the System directory, and change (it should be line 157)

```
zStartupWindowed=0
```

to

```
zStartupWindowed=1
```

After this, I restart the game a couple of times and usually the second time the keyboard finally works. By the way, I only had this problem with the German version, never with the English one. Which one are you playing?

Still, playing the game not full screen sucks, if anybody has a better solution, I will be thankful!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried configuring the keyboard to English (US) first. This works for me !

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with installing font packages 
`winetricks corefonts`